# python 'with' statement and its use in a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, with-statement

I have a TestCase which uses sockets for testing purposes. As you should always close a socket even in the case of some error, I created a context-manager class abstracting a socket.

A test fixture would look like the following, where `MyClassToTest` is the actual class to test which uses the socket device internally.

```
with SocketContextManager() as device:
    foo = MyClassToTest(device)
    # make tests with foo
```

I would like to avoid having these two line repeated in each of the Test fixture, but placed consistently into `setUp`. But how should I do this? The following code

```
def setUp(self):
    with SocketContextManager() as device:
        self.foo = MyClassToTest(device)
```

does not work as the device will be closed at the end of `setUp`. Is there a way to handle the instantiation of the context manager like this, or do I have to repeat it in every test fixture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) for tearDown:

> This is called even if the test method raised an exception

So you can just open the socket in `setUp`, and close it in `tearDown`.  Even if your test case raises an exception, the socket will still be closed.

Comment: Sure, but you have to remember to close the socket down in `tearDown`. The purpose of the `with` statement is that this happens automatically.

Comment: @Alex: That's true, but you have to give up that convenience in a testing situation (or else accept writing the `with` statement in every test).  Setting up and tearing down a test may well require doing some stuff manually that would be done automatically under other conditions, because you're creating a "bubble" for the test to run in and have its errors captured by the test framework.

Comment: Ok, I guess that answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. As BrenBarn pointed out, the unittest framework doesn't support doing what you want, but it seems to me that there's no particular reason why you couldn't adapt it to fit. The `setUp`/`tearDown` pairing is a hangover from other languages that didn't have generators.

The code below defines a new 'ContextTest' class which amalgamates both setUp and tearDown methods into a single generator that both builds and destroys the context for the test. You can drop your `with` statement into the `context()` method along with any other boilerplate.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.3
import unittest

class ContextTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """A unit test where setUp/tearDown are amalgamated into a
    single generator"""
    def context(self):
        """Put both setUp and tearDown code in this generator method
        with a single `yield` between"""
        yield

    def setUp(self):
        self.__context = self.context()
        next(self.__context)
    def tearDown(self):
        for _ in self.__context:
            raise RuntimeError("context method should only yield once")

from contextlib import closing
from urllib.request import urlopen

class MyTest(ContextTest):
    def context(self):
        with closing(urlopen('http://www.python.org')) as self.page:
            yield

    def testFoo(self):
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.page)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```